# CSS reverting to defined style

Tags: css, overriding

In my app a frequently used HTML component is styles as:

```
.box {
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

there are a lot of these (100+) and their border is styled without bottom and different by color:

```
.box:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

...

There's a page in the app where all these boxes need to be displayed with full border (including the bottom border) - what is needed is to remove the 'boder-bottom:none' definitions. So in this specific page I've tried to override the .box definition:

```
.box {
  border-bottom: initial; /* tried unset as well...*/
}
```

But this still results with no border. Is there a way to specify a style so all the .box accepts the full border - or I have to redefine all of the bottom borders?

-Dan

Comment: You'll need to show the (representative) "*[mcve]*" HTML and CSS to allow us to see, and understand, the problem you're facing. I'd expect that the only way to do as you require would be to provide a more specific rule for the situations where you don't want the `border-bottom` to be `none`. But without code I, and we, have no idea what that more-specific rule would be.

Comment: I've updated that question, hope its ok.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define another class for that component and define border-bottom for that class and put it as `!important`

```
.another_class{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef !important;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question as it wasn't clear. I want to remove the 'border-bottom:none' from all of the .box elements.

Answer (score 0):

`border-bottom: initial;` won't give you a border.

Set the second definition to `border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;`

Comment: Can't you just create a second class for that case?